# Making polygons from interpolated points in QGIS

Tags: qgis, interpolation, contour, polygonize, depth

I need to know the extension of the area of a lagoon according to depth classes. I started from a point shapefile containing depth values and used the interpolation plugin and I obtained a raster file. I used the contour function, but I can't convert lines to polygons. I tried the polygonize tool on the raster file, but this function only makes intervals between the polygon of 1,0, whereas I need intervals of 0,5 m.

Comment: Please provide your settings for the polygonize tool.

Comment: I use the tool: Raster > Conversion > Polygonize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Reclassify your data using the Toolbox **Reclassify by table**
2. Run a **raster layer unique values** report

Here's some bathymetry

[image]

Classified using ranges - data outside of ranges are ignored. Assign a unique value for each range.

[image]

The report on the range - third column has the **area in metres**.

[image]

Confirm that summing the areas gives the same total as the area of the original (unclassified) bathymetry.

Comment: thank you very much!